# (logstash) Index only specific data in elasticsearch from kafka input

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I am using kafka as my input and put it in elasticsearch (output)

```
input {
    kafka {
        topics =>["maxwell"]
        codec => json
    }
}
filter {
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        index => 'test_kafka'
        document_type => "%{table}"
        hosts => 'localhost:9200'
    }
}
```

When this runs, it outputs the following json

```
{
  "database": "my_db",
  "xid": 88935,
  "@timestamp": "2016-11-14T12:00:13.763Z",
  "data": {
    "contact_country_code": null,
    "contact_type_id": 1,
    "created": "2014-10-03 12:24:36",
    "modified_by": null,
    "modified": "2014-10-03 12:24:36",
    "contact_id": 1,
    "is_default": 0,
    "created_by": null,
    "contact_number": "1241222232"
  },
  "old": {
    "contact_number": "1241222"
  },
  "commit": true,
  "@version": "1",
  "type": "update",
  "table": "contact",
  "ts": 1479124813
}
```

My question is, how can I only extract the data key with dynamic document_type in elasticsearch to achieve the this one

```
{
  "_index": "test_kafka",
  "_type": "contact",
  "_id": "AVhitY804rvpX8qdVt9d",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "contact_country_code": null,
    "contact_type_id": 1,
    "created": "2014-10-03 12:24:36",
    "modified_by": null,
    "modified": "2014-10-03 12:24:36",
    "contact_id": 1,
    "is_default": 0,
    "created_by": null,
    "contact_number": "1241222232"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ruby` filter to massage your event like below. What it does is first save the `table` field inside the `@metadata` fields so you can reference it in your `elasticsearch` output. Then it deletes all fields except the `data` one. Then it copies all fields inside the `data` field at the root level and finally it deletes the `data` field.

```
input {
    kafka {
        topics =>["maxwell"]
        codec => json
    }
}
filter {
  mutate {
     add_field => { "[@metadata][type]" => "%{table}" }
  }
  ruby {
     code => "
        # Ruby code for Logstash 2.x
        event.to_hash.delete_if {|k, v| k != 'data'}
        event.to_hash.update(event['data'].to_hash)
        event.to_hash.delete_if {|k, v| k == 'data'}

        # Ruby code for Logstash 5.x
        event.to_hash.delete_if {|k, v| k != 'data'}            
        event.to_hash.update(event.get('data').to_hash)
        event.to_hash.delete_if {|k, v| k == 'data'}
     "
  }        
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => 'localhost:9200'
        index => 'test_kafka'
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

Comment: The `event` didn't mutate, btw, I'm using logstash 5.0

Comment: I've also tried replacing the event with this code
```
event = event.get('data')
```
but didn't worked as expected

Comment: Ok, indeed, that's ruby code for Logstash 2.x. Let me fix it for Logstash 5.